# Can't render a react component from onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a React web app. I want to render a component from an onClick. So a user looking through profiles should be able to click on a profile that directs them to the profile/portfolio page. The profiles are mapped through and the onClick is in a map. The code doesn't work though, the `profile` prop passed down is undefined. `profiles` and `profile` information is pulled from Firestore.

Page With Multiple Profiles

```
return (
<div>
            {profiles.map((profile) => {
              const portfolioShow = (profile) => {
                console.log("Portfolio Show: ", profile.user);
                navigate(`/portfolio/${profile.user}`);
                return <Portfolio profile={profile} />;
              };

              return (
                <div
                  key={profile.user}
                  onClick={() => portfolioShow(profile)}
                >
                  // Components that show different profiles.
                </div>
)
```

The `Portfolio Show` console log works and it prints the `profile.user`.

The Portfolio page:

```
export default function Portfolio({ profile }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Profile: ", profile);
  }, [publish, profile]);


  return (
          <>
            // portfolio and profile components
          </>
  );
}
```

The `profile` prop that's passed down is undefined.

Comment: hi good day , with router path you can use a loader to load profile information is pulled from Firestore. it will make sure profile info loaded before component render

Comment: Are  you using react router?

Comment: using createBrowserRouter

Comment: const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: '/your-profile-path', element: <Portfolio />,
        loader : yourExportedloaderMethod
    }
]);

Answer (score 0):

I think the navigation logic is the cause of your problem, in order to solve it use **React Router** to handle navigation to Portfolio while passing the profile data as parameter, here is an example:

```
 import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
 
// your code and other logic here ....


// ... Add this

return (
  <div>
    {profiles.map((profile) => (
      <Link key={profile.user} to={`/portfolio/${profile.user}`}>
        {/* Components that show different profiles */}
      </Link>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

And from Portfolio page use the passed profile data as follow:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

// ...

export default function Portfolio() {
  const { user } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch profile data based on the user parameter
    // Update your state or perform any necessary actions here ...
    console.log("Profile parameter: ", user);
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <>
      {/* Portfolio and profile components */}
    </>
  );
}
```

Make sure you have React Router installed using : (npm install react-router-dom) and that your application is set up to use it.

Comment: I want to pass information/props to the portfolio component instead of pulling it from the database. This is why i need an actual component ```<portfolio profile={profile} />```. There are more props i wanna pass in.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you need to define **portfolioShow**  function out of map.

**like this:**

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
    
export default function MainComponent({ profiles }){
        function portfolioShow(profile) {
            navigate(`/portfolio/${profile.user}`, { state: profile});
        }
    return (
              <div>
                {profiles.map((profile) => {
            
                  return (
                    <div
                      key={profile.user}
                      onClick={() => portfolioShow(profile)}
                    >
                      // Components that show different profiles.
               </div>
           )
 }
```

Then you get **profile state** in ***Portfolio Component*** using useLocaiton() in react-router-dom v 6.

```
 import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Portfolio() {
const location = useLocation();
const profile = location.state

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Profile: ", profile);
  }, [publish, profile]);


  return (
          <>
            // portfolio and profile components
          </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I want to pass information/props to the portfolio component instead of pulling it from the database. This is why i need an actual component <portfolio profile={profile} />. There are more props i wanna pass in.